# Qt: How to "grey out" options using QComboBox (and make unselectable)

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I'm building a GUI using Qt Creator, and I have a dropdown menu using a QComboBox with X many different options. For example, my dropdown has "Apple", "Pear", "Cookie", "Banana". Apple is the first choice (at the top), then pear, and so on.

Using QComboBox, how do I "grey out" the last two options, "Cookie" and "Banana". I want the user to still be able to see the options, but not be able to select them. Almost like a "coming soon feature".

I have tried the solution below, but I am having issues. Any help is appreciated, as I am still new to Qt and its workings.

```
void QComboBox::setItemData(int = 3,false, Qt::UserRole - 1);
void QComboBox::setItemData(int = 4,false, Qt::UserRole - 1);
```

The objectName is: comboBox_4 and is a QComboBox. I placed it in the mainwindow.ui for my project, and the code above I had written in my mainwindow.cpp

I am looking for the easiest implementation of this, not a work-around. So I am able to simply "grey something" out with ease from a dropdown menu using QComboBox.

Comment: Is this the exact code that you have in the CTor of your widget? Because it should be something around `_ui->comboBox_4->setItemData(3, false, Qt::UserRole -1);` Anyway, I am not sure if this will grey out the element, looks likt `setItemData` just substitutes the item in the given position with `QVariant` which is `bool` in your case. But I have not tried it.

Comment: Yes, the code in my original post is what I have in my mainwindow.cpp 

I tried using the code that you provided: 
`_ui->comboBox_4->setItemData(3, false, Qt::UserRole -1); ` 

But was getting the following errors: unknown type name 'ui' and also 'cannot use arrow operator on a type. 

The code at the top of my mainwindow.cpp is the following (not including all the #includes) 
`MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) , ui(new Ui::MainWindow) { ui->setupUi(this); } MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; } `

Comment: @thuga - that looks like another way to solve it (although I haven't tested it). The answer I posted below works and is very straight forward.

Comment: It works, but it's a little hacky way to do it. `Qt::UserRole -1` doesn't really mean anything. If you look at the Qt source code, you will see that it is used internally by the `QStandardItemModel` to store flags. So it working is more of a side effect than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pptaszni was correct. Tested the method below, and it works.

Using the following, I am able to 'grey-out' options and make un-selectable in a QComboBox.

```
_ui->comboBox_4->setItemData(3, false, Qt::UserRole -1);
```

Inside my mainwindow.cpp - the code is as follows, which allows me to choose the 'row' I wanted greyed out.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox_4->setItemData(2, false, Qt::UserRole -1);
    ui->comboBox_4->setItemData(3, false, Qt::UserRole -1);
}
```

Please note that in the above code, 'comboBox_4' refers to my objectName. Don't forget to change this.